# inconvertible types cannot cast android.support.v4.app.fragment to com.google.android.gms.maps.supportmapfragmentmanger

Tags: java, android

Quiero implementar un mapa de google maps en mi aplicación y al crear un nuevo MapsActivity (Que es cógido generado) me salta error en la siguiente línea:

```
 SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
```

El cual es:

> inconvertible types cannot cast android.support.v4.app.fragment to
>   com.google.android.gms.maps.supportmapfragmentmanger

Edit Agrego el codigo de mi actividad y el de mi xml

Mi Actividad:

```
package com.example.tarea6;

import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }


    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
    }
}
```

Mi xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MapsActivity" />
```

Comment: ¿Podrías mostrarnos la actividad al completo?

Comment: Añade si puedes el xml generado de la activity en cuestión

Comment: Listo ya los eh agregado :)

Answer (score 0):

En el xml de tu actividad deberias tener un framelayout con el id= map, qu es donde se mostrara el mapa.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MapsActivity">


    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <fragment xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Eh cambiado el xml como me has dicho pero aun sigue el error :/

Answer (score 0):

**La referencia del elemento `map` que obtienes aquí debe ser un `FrameLayout` para poder usar `getSupportFragmentManager()`**.

```
   SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
```

por lo tanto cambia tu layout a :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Hola gracias por la ayuda, pero al cambiar el layout sigue marcando el mismo error :/

Comment: @HectorMedinaCornejo estas agregando tal y como lo indico en la respuesta o le estas agregando : android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" ?

Comment: Si trate tal y como indicas en respuesta y trate ahorita añadiendo android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" pero igual sigue marcando el error

Comment: no añadas android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" define como lo indico en mi respuesta y revisa que error marca

Comment: Tal y como esta en tu respuesta bota el  error "inconvertible types cannot cast android.support.v4.app.fragment to com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" en la misma linea : SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);